# BigQuery SQL: Return first day of the month, 2 months back from today

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, filtering

I am trying to filter my table for about 2 months of historical data given current date.  The nuance is I want to return history *starting from the first day of the month* ... 2 months back from today.

For example, if today is 8/7/2023 I want my table's filtered date range to be from 6/1/2023 to 8/7/2023 inclusive.

If (hypothetically) today is 3/20/2023 I want my date history to span from 1/1/2023 to 3/20/2023.

Based on research, it looks like the code to do this in SQL is:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_ADD(month, DATE_DIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0)AS DATE)
```

But I'm using BigQuery SQL and I get the following error when I try to run the above line of code:

```
Unrecognized name: month at [1:22]
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_add) for the `DATE_ADD()` function.  It requires a date as the first argument.

Consider the following to guide your query:

```
select date_add(date_trunc(current_date(), month), interval -2 month) as two_months_ago
```